# ProcessWindowFunction#process is not called

Tags: apache-flink

I have a simple code as follows,when I run it within IDE, nothing is printed on the console, could some one help take a look? Thanks

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

object WindowTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    val ds = env.fromElements(
      (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "e"), (5, "f"), (6, "g"), (7, "h"), (8, "g"), (1, "1a"), (2, "2b"), (3, "3c"), (4, "4e"), (5, "5f"), (6, "g"), (7, "h"), (8, "g")
    )
    val ds2 = ds.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
      .process(new ProcessWindowFunction[(Int, String), String, Tuple, TimeWindow] {
        override def process(key: Tuple, context: Context, elements: Iterable[(Int, String)], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
          val k = key.getField[Int](0)
          val w = context.window
          val start = w.getStart
          val end = w.getEnd
          val hc = context.window.hashCode()
          //NOT CALLED
          println(s"k=$k,start=$start, end=$end,hc=$hc")
        }
      })
    ds2.print() 
    env.execute()

    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000)


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ProcessWindowFunction is never called because the window is never triggered. It's never triggered because it runs to completion in a couple of milliseconds (roughly speaking), so it's very unlikely to be running at a moment when the system clock time is exactly at a 10 second boundary, which is what would have to happen for this processing time window to be triggered.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the explanation, can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: What I suspect isn't clear is that the sleep happens in the Flink client (after the job is submitted), but isn't part of what is executed in the workers. They run to completion very quickly.